# How to get prettier and eslint to work together on brace style and indentation?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have prettier and eslint enabled for a new project, and indentation and brace styles get automatically converted to the right format, except in this newly encountered situation:

```
export default class BaseTextMixin
  implements BaseTextMixinType
{
  readTextFile(this: BaseType, link: string): string {
    return (
      this.text_mesh.get(link) ?? fs.readFileSync(link, 'utf-8')
    )
  }
}
```

It shows:

[image]

The first error is:

> Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 2. eslint `indent`

The second error is:

> Opening curly brace does not appear on the same line as controlling statement. eslint `brace-style`

I have this in my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"rules": {
  "curly": 2,
  "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs"],
  "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }]
  // ...
}
```

And I have this in my `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 64,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "proseWrap": "always",
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "prettierPath": "./node_modules/prettier"
}
```

How do I get it to accept that format, since the line-length is too long (it is obeying the line length rule from prettier)? That is, accept the indentation of:

```
export default class BaseTextMixin
  implements BaseTextMixinType
{
```

Do I need to change something with prettier, or eslint?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the `eslint-config-prettier` [plugin](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) for `eslint`. This disables all formatting rules provided by any existing `eslint` plugins.

Also, you need to remove all `eslint` rules that configure any formatting, and let `prettier` handle it all.